# Загрузка Activity

Tags: android

Очень странная ситуация, при загрузке апы есть прелоадер - Activity (Состоит только из одного лейаута), в коде все пару строк которые через 2 секунды запустят новое активити. 
Лейаут имеет фон (320х480) и маленькую картинку. Так вот, на некоторых устройствах (очень многих) при открытии приложения (нажатии на иконку в меню), появляется белый (а где-то черный) экран на 1-2 секунды. Идеи?
Оптимизировать тут уж точно нечего...)

Лейаут:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="290dip"
        android:layout_height="310dip"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
        android:src="@drawable/platetrimed" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Код:

```
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        StartDelay sd = new StartDelay(2000, 1000);
        sd.start();

    }

    public class StartDelay extends CountDownTimer
    {

        public StartDelay(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval)
        {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish()
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
        {}
    }
```

Comment: Показывайте эти две-три строки.

Хотя может просто не находит ресурс...

Comment: покажи леят

Comment: обновил вопрос теперь с кодом

Comment: drawable/platetrimed разложено по всем папкам? или только в одной (к примеру drawable-hpdi/platetrimed

Comment: в hdpi и ldpi (разные картинки - разный размер)

Comment: а xhdpi и mdpi не нужно?

Comment: нет. ну да и в не в этом проблема явно)
Картинку он грузит верную

Comment: а может быть Ваши устройства, где проблемы, как раз с этими?

Comment: Нет, я пробывал помечать картинки, грузит из нужной папки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно только так: не загружать intent -ом отдельные активити, а стереть всё с готовой и добавить нужные элементы.

p.s. А вообще что за устройство тормазячие? Есть у моего знакомого htc wildfire s (кажется), так тот при любом действии тормозит. Так что проще отказаться от поддержки слабенькими девайсами

Answer (score 0):

До загрузки layout'а выполняется куча действий, как раз те две три секунды. Даже пустой активити не покажется сразу.

Чтобы сразу был виден нужный background, его надо указать в теме:

**values/styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/back</item>
</style>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
    ...
    android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" >
```

ЗЫ В эклипсе этот бэкраунд будет виден сразу при редактировании layout'а.